# How to convert a time to javascript-timestamps using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, timestamp

How I will convert this time `11:34` to javascript timestamps. Any javascript functionality available for that.

I am trying to create a floting graph for that I am using Flot library. In my graph time on x axis and count on y axis. For creating data part I need to convert time to timestamp like that thay specified on API doc.

http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/API.txt

This is my code

```
var datasets = {
    "usa": {
        label: "Logged Users",
        data: [[10:55, 4], [11:00, 1], [11:05, 4], [11:10, 2], [11:15, 3], [11:20, 1], [11:25, 5]]
    }
};

if (datasets.length > 0){
    $.plot($("#placeholder"), datasets, {
        yaxis: { min: 0,tickDecimals: 0 },
        xaxis: {  mode: "time",timeformat: "%H:%M" }
    });
}
```

It will not work because I specified exact time instead of a number. So I need to convert that to timestamps format.
Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: is it a timestamp of event recorded or what, describe more on what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an instance of the [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```
var sTime = '11:34';
var oDate = new Date();
oDate.setUTCHours(
    parseInt(sTime.substr(0, 2), 10),
    parseInt(sTime.substr(3, 2), 10),
    0,
    0
);
var sTimestamp = oDate.getTime();
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/H4cFd/4/).

=== UPDATE ===

When the time is local time instead of UTC, then you can set the time with:

```
oDate.setHours(
    parseInt(sTime.substr(0, 2), 10),
    parseInt(sTime.substr(3, 2), 10),
    0,
    0
);
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/H4cFd/3/).

P.s.: the result of `getTime()` is in milliseconds.

=== UPDATE ===

To map your current dataset you can use following script (with UTC; if you want local time remove the UTC in the setter):

```
var aCountries = [ "usa" ];
var oDate = new Date();
oDate.setSeconds(0, 0);
for (var i = 0; i < aCountries.length; i++) {
    datasets[aCountries[i]].data =
        datasets[aCountries[i]].data.map(function(oElement) {
            oDate.setUTCHours(
                parseInt(oElement[0].substr(0, 2), 10),
                parseInt(oElement[0].substr(3, 2), 10)
            );
            return [
                oDate.getTime()
                , oElement[1]
            ];
        });
}
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/cMJKr/).

Comment: Note that the timestamp always contains a "date" part (i.e. the current day). There is no way to create a "hour only" timestamp in JavaScript unless you create your own type.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var now = new Date();

    now.format("m/dd/yy");

// Returns, e.g., 6/09/07

// Can also be used as a standalone function
dateFormat(now, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT");
// Saturday, June 9th, 2007, 5:46:21 PM

// You can use one of several named masks
now.format("isoDateTime");
// 2007-06-09T17:46:21

// ...Or add your own
dateFormat.masks.hammerTime = 'HH:MM! "Can\'t touch this!"';
now.format("hammerTime");
// 17:46! Can't touch this!

// When using the standalone dateFormat function,
// you can also provide the date as a string
dateFormat("Jun 9 2007", "fullDate");
// Saturday, June 9, 2007

// Note that if you don't include the mask argument,
// dateFormat.masks.default is used
now.format();
// Sat Jun 09 2007 17:46:21

// And if you don't include the date argument,
// the current date and time is used
dateFormat();
// Sat Jun 09 2007 17:46:22

// You can also skip the date argument (as long as your mask doesn't
// contain any numbers), in which case the current date/time is used
dateFormat("longTime");
// 5:46:22 PM EST

// And finally, you can convert local time to UTC time. Either pass in
// true as an additional argument (no argument skipping allowed in this case):
dateFormat(now, "longTime", true);
now.format("longTime", true);
// Both lines return, e.g., 10:46:21 PM UTC

// ...Or add the prefix "UTC:" to your mask.
now.format("UTC:h:MM:ss TT Z");
// 10:46:21 PM UTC

Use all date time example .,so use it.
```

Answer (score -1):

I've found the [jQuery Globalization Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate) date parsing to work best. Other methods had cross-browser issues and stuff like date.js had not been updated in quite a while.

You also don't need a datePicker on the page. You can just call something similar to the example given in the docs:

```
$.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', '2007-01-26');
```